# Visual Studio How to debug project A when started by project B?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have a Visual Studio 2015 solution with two projects, AppA and AppB. At a certain point, AppA launches AppB. I would like the debugger to start running when AppB is launched by AppA so I can set breakpoints, etc, in AppB,  but I don't know how to set this up.

Any help would be appreciated!!
Michael

Comment: What does Visual Studio produce as output for AppA and AppB?  Are they .exe or .dll?

Comment: this MUST have been asked many times before, but I can't find where....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the startup code for AppB, add a call to [Debugger.Break](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.break(v=vs.110).aspx).  This will pause execution to allow you to attach a debugger.

Comment: Debugger.Break() didn't cause anything to happen, but I did figure out that Debugger.Launch() did launch the debugger (so thanks for the tip).

Interestingly, if I launch AppB by hand, when the debugger came up, I was able to see source for AppB.  However, if I let AppA launch AppB, the debugger comes up for AppB without source :(

Comment: When running AppB from AppA, do you have the pdb files in the location where AppB is running?